# Multiple Rewrite Rules in .htaccess To Redirect at desired pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I am trying setup a site where i am creating permalinks just like wordpress but specific to the site. So, when a user clicks on article it should should like

```
http://www.sitename.com/url-slug
```

Also when user clicks on directory it should redirect something like this

```
http://www.sitename.com/category/category-slug
```

Similarly, when clicking on sets, users, pages it should redirect respectively like

```
http://www.sitename.com/sets/set-slug

http://www.sitename.com/user/user-full-name
http://www.sitename.com/page/page-slug
```

Following is the code i am using in .htaccess which i am pretty sure is incorrect

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./single.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/ category.php?id=$1 [L]


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Could someone guide me where i am going wrong, i need these pages to call their respective pages i.e. single.php, category.php, sets.php, users.php and page.php respectively to fetch and display data. I am a newbie in .htaccess so, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming that you have no other rules in your .htaccess located int the root directory of you website

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if for an existing directory or file
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
#then do nothing
RewriteRule . - [L]

#otherwise
#if it is for a slug (assuming alphanumeric and dashes), send to single
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ single.php?id=$1 [L]

#if a category 
RewriteRule ^category/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#if a sets
RewriteRule ^sets/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ sets.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#if a sets
RewriteRule ^user/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ users.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#if a page
RewriteRule ^page/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks man! this is what i loved about Stackoverflow. You get answers straight and precise. Thanks a million.